# Why is the soil sample return vehicle in "Life" tumbling?

Tags: life

In the opening scenes of "Life" the soil sample return vehicle was "tumbling" and approaching the station in a way that "no one had trained for." Is this scene just for a more dramatic opening sequence, or were the writers trying to convey that things had already gone wrong with the mission prior to the life form's arrival on the ISS?

Comment: It is clearly shown at the start that the capsule is struck by rocks, and then this is explained by Miranda North.

Comment: Screenshots from two relevant scenes from the first two minutes in the movie: http://imgur.com/a/29Y9i First scene is capsule being struck, second scene is Miranda North talking.

Comment: @BCdotWEB Judging from the last sentence it seems the question is asking what this fact contributes to the story as opposed to what caused it to do this. What's the point of the probe not just returning normally?